# how i can filter out the likes from a Facebook like button, html

Tags: html, css, facebook-like

i have created a fb like button for a page over the fb developer page.
Now my the part of my page which i want to modify looks like this atm

[image]

so my problem is i want to filter out the **likes** (the **188**). And make with this 188 a little paragraph like

> this Sites likes **188**

here is a little example how it should look.

[image]

Thank you guys in  advance

Comment: Using Jquery, you will be bale to retrieve the `text` content of the fb button...

Comment: Do you know what the html looks like for the little "188" balloon you are looking for? If you post that, people can help you figure out the rest.

Comment: <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FAMARIOS%2F136020433084379%3Ffref%3Dts&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: its an iframe from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

You can get Likes by ajax call to this url

http://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/Cyprusjetset

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/Cyprusjetset",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.likes);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Sorry no data found.");
            }
        });
```

see this link http://jsfiddle.net/YFtvU/6/

Comment: thank your for ur fast answer, i will try this immediatly now :-)

Comment: yep, i did this, but i have actually problems to integrate this in html. I put this script in my html file how i can acess now to the likes in a <p> or <div> for example?

Comment: what you get in alert box.?

Comment: actually nothing, but i think i did something wrong. I insertet the script above behind <body> with <script> ..then ur script... </script>

Comment: sry, im a beginner, i cant really follow you where can i find the console?

Comment: press ctrl + shift+ J  for console

Comment: Zeitstempel: 05.04.2013 15:26:42
Fehler: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Quelldatei: file:///C:/Users/Arthur/Desktop/Webdesign/Page/home.html
Zeile: 27

Comment: please include Jquery file.. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript" /> add this line in <head> tag

Comment: @atr what happend did you get any alert box.?

Comment: he referst everytime to this $.ajax when i click on the error

Comment: i going to take a look fast and try it, thank you for your pation and time

Comment: now i have just to put this script in my html file with <script> ...your script... </script> right?